# How i can write glcm features in matlab to excel sheet?

Tags: matlab

I have calculated the glcm features (contrast, homogeneity, energy, correlation), but how can I write only values of these features in an Excel spreadsheet?

These values are in a table. I want to write these values using `xlswrite()` with the `(B2:E2)` range. In other words, I want to write only statistics values for this range, without column names or headers.

Comment: If your data is in a MATLAB table, you're probably better off using `writetable`. What have you tried so far though, and what didn't work the way you wanted? Show your code and some example data.

Comment: Ok , but when I use the writetable function , it will write the names of the columns in addition to their contents, I just want the contents

Answer (score 1):

`xlswrite` can be used with numeric data in a MATLAB array, or text and/or numeric data in a MATLAB cell array. If your data is in a MATLAB table, it's probably easier to use `writetable`.

In the [help for writetable](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html), in the section **Name-Value Pair Arguments**, you can see:

> `'WriteVariableNames'` — Indicator for writing variable names as
>   column headings
>   `true` (default) | `false`

So to write the contents of table `t` to the range `B2:E2` on the first sheet of `mysheet.xlsx` without column headings, you would use

```
writetable(t, 'mysheet.xlsx', 'Sheet', 1, 'Range', 'B2:E2', 'WriteVariableNames', false)
```

Comment: Ok , then i want to write table (t{1,1} ) to range (B2:E2) , and (t{2,1}) to range (B3:B3) , and so on . How to make that based on loop index ? , and how i make dynamic range ?

Comment: I am using matlab to calculate glcm matrix of multiple pictures , when i calculated the glcm matrix on two different computres of same picture , i have get two different matrix of the same picture , so why this problem has happened?